# How can i add constraintrules in the following tables?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I'm stuck with a assignment for school. In the tables in the image it's possible to add the adress (straat), housenumber (huisnummer) and place (plaatsnaam) with a different zip code. So for example i can add this:

- StreetnameA, 12, 1234AB, NEW YORK
- StreetnameA, 12, 6789AB, NEW YORK

I need to add a constraint that checks if the combination of adress, housenumber and place already exist with a zip code. So it can't allow the same combination with a different zip code. Hope you guys can help me.

The database structure must be in Boyce-Codd normal form. That's why i cannot add housenumber to the table STRAATDEEL.

[image: Click for image of tables]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help but need some details. Posting pictures of your tables is not helpful https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 But we tend to discourage doing homework because you don't learn anything.

Comment: You're looking for an `Alter Table` command, most likely. This may point your research in the right direction [ALTER TABLE SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks guys. Can i use a unique constraint on multiple tables? Something like this: ALTER TABLE ADRES AND STRAATDEEL ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE (STRAAT, HUISNUMMER, PLAATSNAAM);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique constraint:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

You will need all 3 columns in one table though, and to be honest I am not 100% sure why you've split out the information into 3 separate tables - looks like you should have one table for addresses.

Comment: Can i use a unique constraint on multiple tables? Something like this: ALTER TABLE ADRES AND STRAATDEEL
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE (STRAAT, HUISNUMMER, PLAATSNAAM);

Comment: @Satyen No you can't. But seriously I'd reconsider having multiple parts of one piece of data in different tables and potentially move then all into one addresses table.

Comment: @Satyen Have a look at how relational databases are designed: https://geekgirls.com/2011/09/databases-from-scratch-iii-relational-design-process/